# Excel VBA, Slicer - How to select 1 item out of a thousand items in excel slicer using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

Let's imagine that we have a slicer with over 1000 items and it keeps growing every day. I'm looking for a solution that I can select only 1 item out of a thousand without scrolling and finding my desired item. The way I see this is like a toggle, where you can turn ON/OFF for a particular item. When you Turn ON - Only that item is selected; when you turn OFF - Slicer filter is cleared.

I tried to record the macro but it will be a thousand lines of code where the slicer items are triggered either True or False, which I don't think will work given that the list is growing everyday.

Thank you for your supports!

Tony

Comment: Hi urdearboy, the input box might work, but the macro after that is where I havent figured out yet.E.g.: You have a slicer with 26 items represent 26 letters in an alphabet, you want to select B, so an input to enter "B", but the macro will run like SlicerItem for "B" = True, the remaining 25 will be False. This way will not work if my list is growing bigger than 26.

Comment: Hi urdearboy, great idea, we can use the month slicer, it will not grow over 12 months. My items will be 12 months, and 1 more for "No Forecast". What is your recommendation on the macro for this solution? What if one of the item does not exist yet?

Comment: Hi urdearboy, OK! Let's say you have a slicer with 12 items for 12 months and another item for "No Forecast". The Macro will work as a toggle to select only "No Forecast", or the other 12 months. given that out of the 12 months, April does not have a forecast, but the macro should still cover April for future use.

Answer (score 0):

May be bellow code is useful, also can you give an example.

```
Sub TestFilter()
    Const FilterCol1 = 4 '........... Your target column
    Const Criteria1 = "something" '.. Your target value
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim LastCol As String

    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        LastCol = Split(.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Address, "$")(1)
        .Range("A1" & ":" & LastCol & LastRow).AutoFilter field:=FilterCol1, Criteria1:=Criteria1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see a slicer control here

Comment: can you provide a picture?